# Disable all but one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I saw [this on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/qGbtQ/1/) and I wanted to know how I would alter it so that if and only if 45 is checked the rest are disabled, if if 45 is unselected then the rest are enabled. I should be able to do all this with out submitting the form.

The example javascript on jsfiddle:

```
$(function(){
    $(".rambo").change(function(){
        $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add proper `id`s and select on that

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="rambo" value='1' /> 45 
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" class="rambo" value='2' /> 56 
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3" class="rambo" value='3' /> 56
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#cb1").change(function(){
        $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));  
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGbtQ/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attribute selector`.

```
$(function(){
    $(".rambo[value=1]").change(function(){
        $(this).siblings().prop("disabled", this.checked);  
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mnmte/

Answer (score 0):

Remove .rambo class from others.

Comment: Oooh. Better way if .rambo has no styling meaning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $(".rambo").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 1){
        $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));  
      }
    });
});
```

One way

Answer (score 0):

Above from all the answers, you can also specify that you only want the 1st `checkbox` to execute the script by using `nth-child` selector:

```
$(".rambo:nth-child(1)").change(function(){
    $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));  
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qGbtQ/10/)