# disable checkboxes not exactly working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So I recently asked a question on how to do this over at [the other question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370119/disable-all-but-one-checkbox/14370746#14370746) where I asked how to change some javascript to make it so that only if a particular check box was checked all check boxes would be disabled.

Well I wrote this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#disable").change(function () {
        $(this).siblings().attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

and over [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83w8s/) you'll see that it doesn't work. The idea is, if you check the first checkbox, all the rest should become disabled. How ever it doesn't.....

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you went wrong with the DOM. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/83w8s/1/

```
$(function () {
  $("#disable").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('.control-group').siblings('.control-group').find('input').attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

Comment: Moreover, you should use .prop() instead of .attr() if you are setting boolean value. the disabled attribute should only accept the value "disabled". The disabled property accept boolean value.

Comment: not entirely true, although it accepts `disabled="true"` it should actually be `disabled="disabled"`

Answer (score 1):

There aren't siblings which type is checkbox.

```
$("#disable").change(function () {
    $('.sidebar').not(this).attr("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to select all the checkboxes without selecting the checked one, then you can disable all the other checkboxes leaving the first checked one as below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#disable").change(function () {
            if($("#disable").is(':checked')){                          
                $("input[type='checkbox']:not(#disable)").attr("disabled", "disabled");                   
            }else{
                $("input[type='checkbox']:not(#disable)").removeAttr("disabled");   
            }
        });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swarne27/e98zK/)