# Checkboxes do not stay disabled on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371541/disable-checkboxes-not-exactly-working#comment19987168_14371541) about how to get a series of checkboxes disabled when ONE is clicked. Well the following code does that: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/83w8s/1/). The problem I have now, and should ave tested for before was form submission.

The checkbox stays clicked but the siblings now remain enabled when they should be disabled. Any tips on what I have to change in the following to make that happen so that as long as the first checkbox remains clicked the rest remain disabled?

```
 $(function () {
      $("#disable").change(function () {
        $(this).closest('.control-group').siblings('.control-group').find('input').attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
      });
    });
```

Comment: You sure you don't want radio boxes?

Comment: add `.change()` to the end of your jQuery expression and it will trigger it immediately.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is the page reloading? Or do you have some AJAX code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your form submission results in a postback. If, as you said, the checkbox will remain checked on this postback, you can modify your code like so:

```
$(function () {
    $("#disable").change(function () {
        $(this).closest('.control-group').siblings('.control-group').find('input').attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
    }).change();  // trigger this immediately
});
```